# jquery datatable checkbox click to select a row

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox, datatable, row

I have a `jquery` `datatable` with checkboxes in first column. For each checkbox select/deselect I want to update a status field of corresponding row in database. I could attach click event handler to the checkboxes. 
With each checkbox click, I want to

1. mark the row containing a `checked` `checkbox` as selected.
2. Get the row data associated with clicked `checkbox`.

The code I have done so far:

```
$('#newItemBasketTab').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
       $('.ibchkclass').click(function() 
       {
          updateItemBasket(this);
       });
    },

    "aaData": result.itembasketdata,
    "aoColumnDefs":
    [
       {"aTargets": [0],"width": "5%","sClass": "centre_class","mData": "item_basket_id",
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ){
          var checkedStatus = '';
          if(data != null) { checkedStatus = "checked"; }
          return "<input type='checkbox' class=\"ibchkclass\" id=\"chk_" + full.id1 + "_" + full.id2 + "\" " + checkedStatus + ">";
         }
       },
       {"aTargets": [1],"width": "35%","mData": "name"},
       {"aTargets": [2],"width": "10%","sClass": "price_class", "mData": "prod_quantity"},
       {"aTargets": [3],"width": "10%", "sClass": "price_class", "mData": "prod_value"}
    ]
});

function updateItemBasket(cb)
{
    var cbid = cb.id;
    if( $('#'+cbid).is(':checked') == true)
    {
        alert('true');
        //Select respective row
        //Get item_basket_id, prod_quantity and prod_value
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the HTML code with an example of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**  `$('#'+cbid).closest("tr");` , you can get the current  parent tr when the  check box is checked using closest function

```
function updateItemBasket(cb)
{
    var cbid = cb.id;
    if( $('#'+cbid).is(':checked') == true)
    {
        alert('true');
       var tr=$('#'+cbid).closest("tr"); // get selected tr
        //Select respective row
        //Get item_basket_id, prod_quantity and prod_value
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I modify as:                                                                                  var clrow = $('#'+cbid).closest("tr");
var aData = table.fnGetData(clrow);
alert(aData.prod_quantity );

Comment: I also want to know whether I can I add a style class to tr variable?

Comment: ya we can add  using  **tr.addClass("className")** or *$('#'+cbid).closest("tr").addClass("className")*

Comment: I add statement : clrow.addClass("selected_row_class"); and I have this in <style> tag.                                                                tr.selected_row_class {
 background-color:red;
}. But color does not change when checkbox is checked.

Comment: you have to remove and add class based on checkbox change